# Horizontally List Item (word suggeston) for MultiAutoComplete Android?

Tags: android, autocomplete, orientation, adapter, android-arrayadapter

How to implement a horizontally word suggestion in my `MultiAutoComplete`?
My array adapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterkata = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.list_item, kata);
txtMessage.setAdapter(adapterkata);
```

My `list_item.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="#000">
</TextView>
```

If I added `LinearLayout` before `TextView` and `orientation = horizontal`, I get force close.